# axios post from lambda function not working

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, axios

Trying to post from aws lambda using axios but it's not working...
I'm not really sure what's going on, but on postman this works.
In the call not configured correctly?

```
exports.handler = async (event) => {
  const body = parseBody(event.body);
  body.phone_number = decrypt(body.phone_number);

  const username = 'SOMETOKEN';
  const password = 'SOMEAPIKEY';
  const token = Buffer.from(`${username}:${password}`, 'utf8').toString('base64');


  const axios = require('axios');
  const url = 'some_url';
  const headers = {
    'Authorization': `Basic ${token}`
  };

  const requestbody = {
    To: '+12122806392',
    From: '+12064622015'
  };
  const params = {headers: headers, body:requestbody};

  console.log('posting');

  axios.post(url, {
    headers: headers,
    body: requestbody
  })
  .then((response) => {
    console.log(response);
  }, (error) => {
    console.log(error);
  });
}
```

Comment: Please provide details, such as what errors you see or what (bad) symptoms you see.

Comment: Tip: If you want people to help, it's wise to help them to help you. Don't make them guess what error message you're seeing, or what's not working.

Comment: Try `axios.post(url, requestBody, { headers })`.

Comment: the problem is that there are no errors or anything...